# Programmatically check if "Share iTunes Library XML with other applications" is disabled

Tags: itunes, preferences, plist

iTunes update (10.2.0.145) seems to have added new advanced feature "Share iTunes LIbrary XML with other applications" which if disabled no longers outputs the `Music Library.xml`.

Our applications is highly depended on that file, which by [this documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201610) states the file will be available. Anyone know how to set, or check if that preference is disabled? I have looked at the com.apple.iTunes.plist, but nothing there seemed to reflect that setting.

Comment: I have the same problem. Seems, this setting is stored in database -- iTunes Library.itl file. But format of this binary file is undocumented.

Comment: exactly, not only is it not documented it's also encrypted. I found this library that could be useful. But it no longer works: https://github.com/josephw/titl. For now, I'm just going to warn our users that they have to enable this in order for our app to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for mac.
mac solution "ShareiTunesLibrary.applescript"

```
activate application "iTunes"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        keystroke "," using command down
        repeat until exists toolbar 1 of window 1
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        tell window 1
            if title does not contain "Advanced" then
                click button "Advanced" of toolbar 1
            end if
            repeat until its title starts with "Advanced"
                delay 0.2
            end repeat
            tell checkbox "Share iTunes Library XML with other applications" of group 1
                if value is not 1 then
                    click it
                end if
            end tell
            click button "OK"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

stuck in windows

Comment: If u have any information around mac ,please share

Comment: Nice. I basically just end up checking if the xml file exists or not on windows. Not the best way, but did the trick.

Comment: so how you  are able to get itunes data without its itunes media library.xml in windows.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. Currently, I display a warning to the user letting them know they must enable that feature if they want integration with iTunes. Not ideal, but it works.